# Compilation error when more than 4 items in a C# Tuple

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an MVC project and i have a view that is binded to multiple models. For this case, i used a Tuple to pass those models from the controller to the view. The problem is that whenever the number of Tuple items exceeds 4 items, i start getting a comiplation error "Syntax error, '>'"

This is how im returning the tuple in controller:

```
return View(new Tuple<Product, List<ProductBuildType>, List<NutritionValueView>, List<SelectListItem>, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>>(product, productBuildTypes, productValuesList, items, countriesList));
```

This is my tuple from the view:

```
@model Tuple<FWH.Services.Models.Menu.Product, List<FWH.Services.Models.Menu.ProductBuildType>, List<FWH.Services.Models.Menu.UI.NutritionValueView>, List<SelectListItem>, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>>
```

Can you please help?

Comment: Where do you get this error? The controller or the model.

Comment: On a side note: Why don't you use a class model?

Comment: When you start tuple'ing with 4+ pieces, you should really create a  structure or class for coupling that data instead of gluing it up on the fly with tuple

Comment: Also, this is very strange that exactly 4+ are resulting in an error. Tuple is limited in width, but it should cover up to something like 7-8 items if I remember correctly. Are you sure you are using a Tuple from core .Net libraries, not any "backports" or 3rd party libs?

Comment: Also, where exactly do you get that `SyntaxError >`? is that in cshtml or cs file? can you create a minimal example or at least show more surrounding code? have you tried it with simpler Tuple with no nested generics like `Tuple<int,int,int,int,int>` or different complex generic like `List<List<List<int>>>`?

Comment: 1- This error is not in cs not cshtml. It is in the Error List but not in any file

Comment: 2- using a class model is an alternative solution bass still need to know whats the issue with the Tuple

Comment: I get the same error when using simple types like a Tuple of 5 integer items

Comment: If it's in the ErrorList, then one of the utilities used to build/deploy/wtf the project must have produced that error. Try double-clicking on that message, it may then jump to the file, or may not. If it does not, please read all the columns in the ErrorList carefully and check where it comes from. It should be listed there in some column, along with file name. If there's really no details there, then go to the Output window and check there. Remember that the Output window has several log types (build, debug, deploy, ..) so try switching between them and check all them.

Comment: If there's nothing in any of the output window's logs, rightclick and "clean" the solution, go to Output, "clear all", and rebuild and check the Output window again

Comment: Also, the ErrorList window sometimes shows you errors that come straight from the editor/designer/etc file viewers/editors. Try closing all tabs with all files, clean&rebuild the solution and check what ErrorList/Output say. If error disappears, try reopening one-by-one all the filetabs you had opened before and check when the error pops back. If it does, you will learn which file has problems.

Comment: Last word - when the error does not show up during build, but shows up when you open/view/edit the file in visual studio, this may mean that: (A) either the file has problems but this file NOT checked duing build (like i.e. plan HTML) or (B) either the file doesnt have any problems and it's just the code parser from VS that fails to parse it (if so, well, ignore it and live further, or try escalating the bug to MS)

Comment: Ok.. yet one more thing.. the ErrorList can also be populated with notes from just about any VS plugin you've installed.. So if you have some things like resharper or whatever, the message may be generated by them. However, in that case, the message is usually well described either in ErrorList or Output.. so, well..

Comment: I am also facing similar issues. I think it's better to create class if we have more than 4 items in tuple.